# Forbid using named arguments in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there a way in Scala to forbid using named arguments for a function?

Example:

```
def func(num: Int, power: Int) = math.pow(num, power)

func(3, 2)                   // OK
func(num = 3, power = 2)     // Forbidden
```

Comment: Lint tool is acceptable?

Comment: Go for it, any method is acceptable. But simpler is better.

Comment: What is the reason for disallowing this standard syntax?

Comment: @0__: No reason, just curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a function literal:

```
val func = (num: Int, power: Int) => math.pow(num, power)

func(3, 2)
func(num = 3, power = 2)  // "error: not found: value num"
```

(Although `Function2`'s `apply` still has argument names:)

```
func(v1 = 3, v2 = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would suggest:

```
apm@mara:~$ scalac -deprecation -Xfatal-warnings
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130923-052707-7d570b54c3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def f(@deprecatedName('x) x: Int) = 2 * x
f: (x: Int)Int

scala> f(3)
res0: Int = 6

scala> f(x = 4)
<console>:9: warning: naming parameter x has been deprecated.
              f(x = 4)
                  ^
error: No warnings can be incurred under -Xfatal-warnings.
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way today, although it's an [easy tweak](https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/tree/issue/deprecate-name).

The error you'd see today is:

```
error: deprecated parameter name x has to be distinct from any other parameter name (deprecated or not).
```

Does it make sense to deprecate the current name of a parameter?

The JavaDoc says:

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are
>   discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because
>   a better alternative exists.

If you can motivate discouraging users from using named arguments when calling a function, then you should be able to deprecate that usage outright.

Maybe there is better wording for the new error:

```
warning: that parameter is he-who-must-not-be-named!
```